# Wrong image orientation for jpegs in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to upload images to an RMarkdown html document. I have been using the include_graphics() function to load .jpg files from my working directory.

Most images upload correctly, but some are flipped 90 degrees. This error only happens to portrait images.

The same error occurs if I try to upload them in-line, outside of a chunk.

I've opened these images in Windows Explorer and they are in the correct orientation. They are also correct when opened in MS Paint or in Google Drive. Interestingly, if I convert the portrait jpegs to .png files, they then appear in their correct portrait orientation in RMarkdown. I would be fine with this fix, but .png files increase the size of my html document dramatically so I'd prefer to use the original .jpg images.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "C:/Users/Harrison/Documents/Project")
````

Sample image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Killington_trail.jpg

```
## in-line example (wrong orientation)
![trail]\(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Killington_trail.jpg)

## chunk example (after saving the image to working directory folder as "image.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics("image.jpg") # produces same orientation error

# save image.jpg as a png file and try again
knitr::include_graphics("image.png") # produces correct orientation
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Comment: It'd be easier if you provided a minimal example, i.e., a minimal rmarkdown code and one of those JPG that get flipped.

Comment: This is because of exif data in the image. Some browsers honor the exif rotation. Check your own image [with a tool like this](http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi) (look for "Rotate"). You want to remove the exif data from the images.

Comment: That solved it! It was the exif image orientation. Thanks!